# Two Gmail filters applied to the same email

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I'm having an issue where 2 filters are being applied to a single email.  Resulting in that email ending up in two different labels.

As an example: Filter A is for a general email box that multiple people have access to
               Filter B is for an individual.

If the individual does a reply all it puts both the general email and individual email on the reply, when it hits my filters I end up with copies in both the general email label and the individuals label.

I've tried variations on both filters, but can't seem to keep this from happening.
Would appreciate any help or tips that I can use to keep this from happening.

Comment: Welcome. Please follow the [tour], read [ask] and add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

> when it hits my filters I end up with copies in both the general email
>   label and the individuals label.

Because gmail uses labels instead of folders there isn't a copy of the email. The message/conversation just has two labels. A label is just a tag placed on the message/conversation to make it easier to find related items.

You would have to write the filters to be more complex so that only one is applied, if you don't want both labels.